# How to calculate the wedge product of three terms

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

This question was asked in my assignment on Linear Algebra and I am struck on it because I am not very good in Wedge products .

> Question:  Suppose the standard co-ordinate on $\mathbb{R}^3$  are x,y,z. Now using spherical co-ordinates write $x=\rho cos(\theta) cos(\phi)$, $y =cos(\theta) sin(\phi)$ and $z= sin (\theta)$. Calculate dx, dy, dz and $dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$ in terms of $d \rho $ , $d\theta$ , $d \phi$.

I have calculated the dx , dy and dz but I am not sure how should I proceed to find the wedge product. In my notes it is given that if $w \in A^k (v)$ , $n \in A^r(v) $ then $w\wedge n = Alt(w \otimes n) \times \frac{(k+r)!} { k! r!} $ and related results but I am having a hard time implementing it.

Can you please help me with calculating wedge product?

Comment: Forget above the definition, use the fact wedge product is distributive, associative and anti-commutative. Once you express each of $dx, dy, dz$ as linear combination of $d\rho, d\theta, d\phi$. You use above 3 laws to reorder the products of $d\rho$, $d\theta$, $d\phi$ into correct order.

Comment: @achillehui I know all these properties but can you show how it would be done.

Comment: $y$ and $z$ are missing factors of $\rho$.

Comment: @mr_e_man I know, but the question is written as it was in assignment. I checked it again.

Comment: As it's written, it's not spherical coordinates. It must be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\displaystyle\;\left\{\begin{align} 
x &= \rho\cos\theta\cos\phi\\
y &= \cos\theta\sin\phi\\
z &= \sin\theta
\end{align}\right.$, we have

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rlll}
dx &= \cos\theta\cos\phi\; d\rho &- \rho\sin\theta \cos\phi\; d\theta &- \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\; d\phi\\
dy &= &-\sin\theta\sin\phi\;d\theta &+ \cos\theta\cos\phi\;d\phi\\
dz &= &+\cos\theta\;d\theta
\end{array}\right.$$
So
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
dy \wedge dz &= 
\left( -\sin\theta\sin\phi\; d\theta + \cos\theta\cos\phi\; d\phi \right)
\wedge ( \cos\theta\; d\theta )\\
&=-\color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\theta\; d\theta\wedge d\theta}}}
+ \cos^2\theta\cos\phi\; d\phi \wedge d\theta\\
&= - \cos^2\theta \cos\phi\; d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
$$
and hence
$$\begin{align}
dx \wedge dy \wedge dz
&= (\cos\theta\cos\phi\; d\rho - \rho\sin\theta \cos\phi\; d\theta - \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\; d\phi )\wedge (-\cos^2\theta\cos\phi\; d\theta \wedge d\phi)\\
&= -\cos^2\theta\cos\phi \left(
\begin{array}{ll}
+ \cos\theta\cos\phi\; d\rho \wedge d\theta \wedge d\phi \\
- \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\rho\sin\theta \cos\phi\; d\theta \wedge d\theta \wedge d\phi}}}\\
- \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\; d\phi \wedge d\theta \wedge d\phi}}}
\end{array}
\right)\\
&= -\cos^3\theta\cos^2\phi\;d\rho \wedge d\theta \wedge d\phi
\end{align}
$$

In actual computation, one typically won't show all those terms which vanish because
it contains some $d(\cdot)$ twice.

For an example, since $dz$ only contains $d\theta$, in computing $dy \wedge dz$, we will ignore the $d\theta$ component of $dy$ and directly writes down

$$dy \wedge dz = \cos^2\theta\cos\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta = \cdots$$

Similarly, since $dy \wedge dz$ only contains $d\theta \wedge d\phi$, in computation of $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$, we only need to consider the $d\rho$ component in $dx$
and directly write down
$$dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = (\cos\theta \cos\phi d\rho) \wedge (-\cos^2\theta\cos\phi \;d\theta \wedge d\phi) = \cdots$$